# how to get address from latlan on android

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to have the address of that point when I have a location. I used the code below, but sometimes I do not care about it, and I do not even find the province and the city. Thank you very quickly for help.

List addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(x), Double.parseDouble(y), 1);

```
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                cityName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName();
                stateName = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
                countryName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            }
```

Comment: What is coordinate where you cannot get any result?

Comment: @xomena the result is NULL

Comment: What is a value of latitude and longitude where you get NULL response?

Comment: @xomena For some lengths of latitude, some phones have this problem. The problem is not always